# Finding equation using vectors and norm

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

Find equation for the line through $P\left(7,\,3,\,-1\right)$ and  parallel to $\mathbf{a}=\left\langle-3,\,8,\,7\right\rangle$.

Comment: Welcome to Stackexchange. Simple "Here's my exercise, solve it for me" posts usually get few responses. It is better to say what you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc. Something to both show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help.

Comment: @Frentos got it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write it like this.
${x-7\over -3} = {y-3\over 8} = {z+1\over 7}$

OR

$(-3t+7 , 8t+3 , 7t-1 )$

OR

$7\hat{i} +3 \hat{j}-\hat{k} +t(-3\hat{i}+8\hat{j}+7\hat{k})$

Answer (score 0):

Solved: Simply attach a t to the vector -3t, 8t, 7t and then add the points from the point given therefore -3t+7, 8t+3, 7t-1